# HAProxy 1.5.12 hdr(<name>)/hdr_?

Tags: reverse-proxy, haproxy

I ma trying to figure out which of the `hdrs` to use in this situation. According to the documentation http://www.haproxy.org/download/1.5/doc/configuration.txt the following is stated:

```
 hdr(<name>) The HTTP header <name> will be looked up in each HTTP
                  request. Just as with the equivalent ACL 'hdr()' function,
                  the header name in parenthesis is not case sensitive. If the
                  header is absent or if it does not contain any value, the
                  roundrobin algorithm is applied instead.

                  An optional 'use_domain_only' parameter is available, for
                  reducing the hash algorithm to the main domain part with some
                  specific headers such as 'Host'. For instance, in the Host
                  value "haproxy.1wt.eu", only "1wt" will be considered.

                  This algorithm is static by default, which means that
                  changing a server's weight on the fly will have no effect,
                  but this can be changed using "hash-type".
```

1) Where is the list of different `<name>`s?

2)  Which one do I use when trying to use haproxy as a reverse proxy in this case (subdomains), would I use hdr() or would I use hdr_dom() for example:

```
acl host_deusexmachina  hdr(<name>) -i deus.ex.machina.mydomain.com
acl host_fela           hdr(<name>) -i fela.mydomain.com
acl host_mydomain       hdr(<name>) -i mydomain.com
```

Answer (score 0):

1. The different names are the [headers available in the HTTP protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields).
2. You should probably use `Host`.